# React-redux:Why I dispatch an action the state changed but the view not update?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I combine reducers and add initial states in index.js.

```
const store = createStore(Reducers, initialState);
```

and `mapDispatchToProps` like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps)=>({
    getAboutMeData: ()=> dispatch(getAboutMeData())
});
```

and my actions is this:

```
export const getAboutMeData = () => ({
    type: GET_ABOUTME_DATA,
    payload:{
        basicInfo: {
            name: "change data",
            job: "change data",
            hometown: "change data",
            birthday: "change data",
            degree: "change data",
            livein: "change data",
            avater: "change data",
            school: "change data",
            majorIn: "change data"
        }
    }

})
```

I update my component when use `componentDidMount` by:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    const {getAboutMeData}  =this.props;
    getAboutMeData();
}
```

and my reducers is this:

```
export default function aboutMe(state= {}, action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case GET_ABOUTME_DATA:
    return action.payload
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

but my component did not update state and I did not know why.

Comment: do you have mapStateToProps configured

Comment: yes,I did,   const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => (
{
  aboutMe: state.aboutMe
})
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AboutMe)

Comment: can you show the code for your component

Comment: github address:
https://github.com/huxinmin/huxinmin.github.io/tree/master/app

Answer (score 0):

Components are updated only with props or state changes.
So dispatching an action and updating a component are irrelevant.

You should configure mapStateToProps like below

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        aboutMe: state.aboutMe
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps)=>({
    getAboutMeData: ()=> dispatch(getAboutMeData())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

Comment: yes, I did absolutely as you told me, but it did not work.

Comment: Hm..
Checking the "shouldComponentUpdate" method if the component has.

And debug the store's state object. I recommend you install the redux-devtools :: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools